# UITableView datasource method does not call in Device 3G iOS4.0

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

When I call this Code

```
[[self tableView]reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:kSectionShoppingList]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

HeightForRowAtIndexPath Calls
But in CellForRowAtIndexPath for section 3 row 0 does not call.

Looking for your suggestion.

and it is specific to Device 3g iOS4.0.1.

Is anyone earlier have faced same issue.

Comment: ReloadData reload the whole table . that works like charm. but still why reloadRowAtIndexPath dint wotk ??????????

Comment: Have you tried to use it into -beginUpdates -endUpdates? Nevertheless,  I suppose the row is being displayed because if it is not, then cellForRowAtIndexPath has not to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue i have mentioned look like a bug in iOs4.0.1. anyway I have solved it by reloading whole table using `reloadData` method  instead of reloading particular rows.

Answer (score 0):

Is the cell you are reloading visible ?

Not sure about iOS4.0.1, don't have it installed to test, but on iOS5+, the cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called if the cell is not visible, just tried it in one of my apps.

Comment: its normal behavior. cellForRowatIndexPath calls before the cell appears on the screen. Anyway the issue i have mentioned is an bug in iOs4.0.1. anyway I have solved it by reloading whole table instead of reloading perticular rows.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are reloading sections and rows that are visible and corresponding the the right indices in your tableview. Also check that your tableView delegate and datasource are correctly set.

reloadData  method as the following comment :

`- (void)reloadData;                 // reloads everything from scratch. redisplays visible rows. because we only keep info about visible rows, this is cheap. will adjust offset if table shrinks`

you may also have trouble reloading single rows if your table is mutating, then you should beginUpdate / endUpdate methods

```
- (void)beginUpdates;   // allow multiple insert/delete of rows and sections to be animated simultaneously. Nestable
- (void)endUpdates;     // only call insert/delete/reload calls or change the editing state inside an update block.  otherwise things like row count, etc. may be invalid.
```

Comment: reloadRowsAtIndexPaths method is reloading the rows as expected in all iOS version except iOS4.0.1.

Comment: if it is iOS4.0.1 only, it may be a bug. You can test if it is this specific version of the OS and perform a full table view reload.